# Fourth inner join to the same table increases query duration significantly

Tags: innodb, performance, mysql-5.1, mysql-5, query-performance

As soon as I add a fourth inner join to a specific table, the query duration increases significantly: sub 1sec to 45sec.

The table in question is `deployments d4`.

The SQL Query:

```
select 
  a.id as asset_id,
  a.asset_group_id,
  ac.id as asset_configuration_id,
  ac.domain_id,
  ac.server_id,
  e.acronym as environment,
  e.id as environment_id,
  d.name as domain,

  -- last deployment
  d1.id as last_deployment_id,
  d1.revision as last_revision, 
  d1.deployed_date as last_deployed_date,
  d1.deployed_by as last_deployed_by,
  d1.is_failed as last_is_failed,

  -- last successful deployment
  d2.id as last_successful_deployment_id, 
  d2.revision as last_successful_revision, 
  d2.deployed_date as last_successful_deployed_date,
  d2.deployed_by as last_successful_deployed_by,

  -- last successful environment deployment
  d3.revision as last_successful_environment_revision,
  d3.deployed_date as last_successful_environment_deployed_date,

  -- last environment deployment
  d4.revision as last_environment_revision,
  d4.deployed_date as last_environment_date,
  d4.is_failed as last_environment_is_failed

from 
  assets a
  inner join asset_configurations ac on a.id=ac.asset_id
  inner join domains d on ac.domain_id=d.id
  inner join servers s on ac.server_id=s.id
  inner join environments_servers es on s.id=es.server_id
  inner join environments e on es.environment_id=e.id

  -- last deployment
  inner join deployments d1 on ac.id=d1.asset_configuration_id
  inner join vw_last_deployment_statuses ld on d1.asset_configuration_id = ld.asset_configuration_id and d1.deployed_date=ld.deployed_date

  -- last successful deployment
  inner join deployments d2 on ac.id=d2.asset_configuration_id
  inner join vw_last_successful_deployment_statuses lsd on d2.asset_configuration_id = lsd.asset_configuration_id and d2.deployed_date=lsd.deployed_date

  -- last successful environment deployment
  inner join deployments d3 on ac.id=d3.asset_configuration_id
  inner join vw_last_successful_environment_deployment_statuses lsed on a.id=lsed.asset_id and e.id=lsed.environment_id and d3.deployed_date=lsed.deployed_date

  -- last environment deployment
  inner join deployments d4 on ac.id=d4.asset_configuration_id
  inner join vw_last_environment_deployment_statuses led on a.id=led.asset_id and e.id=led.environment_id and d4.deployed_date=led.deployed_date

  where ac.id = 169;
```

**Update #1**

Here is the explain **WITHOUT** fourth inner join:

```
id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,Extra
1,PRIMARY,ac,const,"PRIMARY,FK_asset_configurations_assets_id,FK_asset_configurations_domains_id,FK_asset_configurations_servers_id",PRIMARY,4,const,1,
1,PRIMARY,d,const,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,const,1,
1,PRIMARY,s,const,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,const,1,"Using index"
1,PRIMARY,a,const,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,const,1,
1,PRIMARY,es,ref,"PRIMARY,FK_environments_servers_servers_id2",FK_environments_servers_servers_id2,4,const,1,"Using index"
1,PRIMARY,e,eq_ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,aps_cmdb.es.environment_id,1,
1,PRIMARY,d1,ref,FK_deployments_asset_configurations_id,FK_deployments_asset_configurations_id,4,const,55,
1,PRIMARY,d2,ref,FK_deployments_asset_configurations_id,FK_deployments_asset_configurations_id,4,const,55,
1,PRIMARY,d3,ref,FK_deployments_asset_configurations_id,FK_deployments_asset_configurations_id,4,const,55,
1,PRIMARY,<derived4>,ALL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,171,"Using where; Using join buffer"
1,PRIMARY,<derived3>,ALL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,227,"Using where; Using join buffer"
1,PRIMARY,<derived2>,ALL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,230,"Using where; Using join buffer"
4,DERIVED,a,index,PRIMARY,FK_assets_asset_package_deployment_methods_id,1,NULL,101,"Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort"
4,DERIVED,ac,ref,"PRIMARY,FK_asset_configurations_assets_id,FK_asset_configurations_servers_id",FK_asset_configurations_assets_id,4,aps_cmdb.a.id,1,
4,DERIVED,s,eq_ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,aps_cmdb.ac.server_id,1,"Using index"
4,DERIVED,es,ref,FK_environments_servers_servers_id2,FK_environments_servers_servers_id2,4,aps_cmdb.ac.server_id,1,"Using index"
4,DERIVED,d,ref,FK_deployments_asset_configurations_id,FK_deployments_asset_configurations_id,4,aps_cmdb.ac.id,42,"Using where"
3,DERIVED,deployments,index,NULL,FK_deployments_asset_configurations_id,4,NULL,9877,"Using where"
2,DERIVED,deployments,index,NULL,FK_deployments_asset_configurations_id,4,NULL,9877,
```

Here is the explain **WITH** fourth inner join:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY ac  const   PRIMARY,FK_asset_configurations_assets_id,FK_asset_configurations_domains_id,FK_asset_configurations_servers_id PRIMARY 4   const   1   
1   PRIMARY d   const   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   const   1   
1   PRIMARY s   const   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   const   1   "Using index"
1   PRIMARY a   const   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   const   1   
1   PRIMARY es  ref PRIMARY,FK_environments_servers_servers_id2 FK_environments_servers_servers_id2 4   const   1   "Using index"
1   PRIMARY e   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   aps_cmdb.es.environment_id  1   
1   PRIMARY d1  ref FK_deployments_asset_configurations_id  FK_deployments_asset_configurations_id  4   const   55  
1   PRIMARY d2  ref FK_deployments_asset_configurations_id  FK_deployments_asset_configurations_id  4   const   55  
1   PRIMARY d3  ref FK_deployments_asset_configurations_id  FK_deployments_asset_configurations_id  4   const   55  
1   PRIMARY d4  ref FK_deployments_asset_configurations_id  FK_deployments_asset_configurations_id  4   const   55  
1   PRIMARY <derived4>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    171 "Using where; Using join buffer"
1   PRIMARY <derived5>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    174 "Using where; Using join buffer"
1   PRIMARY <derived3>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    227 "Using where; Using join buffer"
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    230 "Using where; Using join buffer"
5   DERIVED a   index   PRIMARY FK_assets_asset_package_deployment_methods_id   1   NULL    101 "Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort"
5   DERIVED ac  ref PRIMARY,FK_asset_configurations_assets_id,FK_asset_configurations_servers_id    FK_asset_configurations_assets_id   4   aps_cmdb.a.id   1   
5   DERIVED s   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   aps_cmdb.ac.server_id   1   "Using index"
5   DERIVED es  ref FK_environments_servers_servers_id2 FK_environments_servers_servers_id2 4   aps_cmdb.ac.server_id   1   "Using index"
5   DERIVED d   ref FK_deployments_asset_configurations_id  FK_deployments_asset_configurations_id  4   aps_cmdb.ac.id  42  
4   DERIVED a   index   PRIMARY FK_assets_asset_package_deployment_methods_id   1   NULL    101 "Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort"
4   DERIVED ac  ref PRIMARY,FK_asset_configurations_assets_id,FK_asset_configurations_servers_id    FK_asset_configurations_assets_id   4   aps_cmdb.a.id   1   
4   DERIVED s   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   aps_cmdb.ac.server_id   1   "Using index"
4   DERIVED es  ref FK_environments_servers_servers_id2 FK_environments_servers_servers_id2 4   aps_cmdb.ac.server_id   1   "Using index"
4   DERIVED d   ref FK_deployments_asset_configurations_id  FK_deployments_asset_configurations_id  4   aps_cmdb.ac.id  42  "Using where"
3   DERIVED deployments index   NULL    FK_deployments_asset_configurations_id  4   NULL    9877    "Using where"
2   DERIVED deployments index   NULL    FK_deployments_asset_configurations_id  4   NULL    9877
```

**Update #2**

Example of `vw_last_deployment_status`

```
select 
        `aps_cmdb`.`deployments`.`asset_configuration_id` AS `asset_configuration_id`,
        max(`aps_cmdb`.`deployments`.`deployed_date`) AS `deployed_date`
    from
        `aps_cmdb`.`deployments`
    group by `aps_cmdb`.`deployments`.`asset_configuration_id`
```

**Update #3**

Extracted all view select statements and bundled it all into one statement:

```
select
  a.id as asset_id,
  a.asset_group_id,
  ac.id as asset_configuration_id,
  ac.domain_id,
  ac.server_id,
  e.acronym as environment,
  e.id as environment_id,
  d.name as domain,

  -- last deployment
  d1.id as last_deployment_id,
  d1.revision as last_revision, 
  d1.deployed_date as last_deployed_date,
  d1.deployed_by as last_deployed_by,
  d1.is_failed as last_is_failed,

  -- last successful deployment
  d2.id as last_successful_deployment_id, 
  d2.revision as last_successful_revision, 
  d2.deployed_date as last_successful_deployed_date,
  d2.deployed_by as last_successful_deployed_by,

  -- last successful environment deployment
  d3.revision as last_successful_environment_revision,
  d3.deployed_date as last_successful_environment_deployed_date

  -- last environment deployment
  -- d4.revision as last_environment_revision,
  -- d4.deployed_date as last_environment_date,
  -- d4.is_failed as last_environment_is_failed

from 
  assets a
  inner join asset_configurations ac on a.id=ac.asset_id
  inner join domains d on ac.domain_id=d.id
  inner join servers s on ac.server_id=s.id
  inner join environments_servers es on s.id=es.server_id
  inner join environments e on es.environment_id=e.id

  -- last deployment
  inner join deployments d1 on ac.id=d1.asset_configuration_id
  inner join (
    select 
        `aps_cmdb`.`deployments`.`asset_configuration_id` AS `asset_configuration_id`,
        max(`aps_cmdb`.`deployments`.`deployed_date`) AS `deployed_date`
    from
        `aps_cmdb`.`deployments`
    group by `aps_cmdb`.`deployments`.`asset_configuration_id`) ld on d1.asset_configuration_id = ld.asset_configuration_id and d1.deployed_date=ld.deployed_date

  -- last successful deployment
  inner join deployments d2 on ac.id=d2.asset_configuration_id
  inner join (
    select 
        `aps_cmdb`.`deployments`.`asset_configuration_id` AS `asset_configuration_id`,
        max(`aps_cmdb`.`deployments`.`deployed_date`) AS `deployed_date`
    from
        `aps_cmdb`.`deployments`
    where
        (`aps_cmdb`.`deployments`.`is_failed` = 0)
    group by `aps_cmdb`.`deployments`.`asset_configuration_id`) lsd on d2.asset_configuration_id = lsd.asset_configuration_id and d2.deployed_date=lsd.deployed_date

  -- last successful environment deployment
  inner join deployments d3 on ac.id=d3.asset_configuration_id
  inner join (
    select 
        `a`.`id` AS `asset_id`,
        `es`.`environment_id` AS `environment_id`,
        max(`d`.`deployed_date`) AS `deployed_date`
    from
        ((((`aps_cmdb`.`deployments` `d`
        join `aps_cmdb`.`asset_configurations` `ac` ON ((`d`.`asset_configuration_id` = `ac`.`id`)))
        join `aps_cmdb`.`assets` `a` ON ((`ac`.`asset_id` = `a`.`id`)))
        join `aps_cmdb`.`servers` `s` ON ((`ac`.`server_id` = `s`.`id`)))
        join `aps_cmdb`.`environments_servers` `es` ON ((`s`.`id` = `es`.`server_id`)))
    where
        (`d`.`is_failed` = 0)
    group by `a`.`id` , `es`.`environment_id`) lsed on a.id=lsed.asset_id and e.id=lsed.environment_id and d3.deployed_date=lsed.deployed_date

  -- last environment deployment
  inner join deployments d4 on ac.id=d4.asset_configuration_id
  inner join (
    select 
        `a`.`id` AS `asset_id`,
        `es`.`environment_id` AS `environment_id`,
        max(`d`.`deployed_date`) AS `deployed_date`
    from
        ((((`aps_cmdb`.`deployments` `d`
        join `aps_cmdb`.`asset_configurations` `ac` ON ((`d`.`asset_configuration_id` = `ac`.`id`)))
        join `aps_cmdb`.`assets` `a` ON ((`ac`.`asset_id` = `a`.`id`)))
        join `aps_cmdb`.`servers` `s` ON ((`ac`.`server_id` = `s`.`id`)))
        join `aps_cmdb`.`environments_servers` `es` ON ((`s`.`id` = `es`.`server_id`)))
    where
        (`d`.`is_failed` = 0)
    group by `a`.`id` , `es`.`environment_id`
) led on a.id=led.asset_id and e.id=led.environment_id and d4.deployed_date=led.deployed_date

  where ac.id = 169;
```

**Update #4**

Even with the extracted view SQL, the single statement takes 40 seconds with the fourth inner join.

I also created a deployment view from the deployment table where the single blob field was omitted. Still takes 40 seconds.

**Update #5**

Doing a bit more profiling...

Without inner join:

- Innodb_rows_read 188 548 The number of rows read from InnoDB tables.
- Innodb_data_read 19 349 504  The amount of data read so far, in bytes.

With inner join:

- Innodb_rows_read 19 207 716  The number of rows read from InnoDB tables.
- Innodb_data_read 2 147 205 120   The amount of data read so far, in bytes.

Comment: How is that *four* inner joins?  I see 11 *prior* to the join mentioned in your question.

Comment: @MaxVernon yeah, it's more the fourth inner join to a specific table...

Comment: Are all those tables base tables or are some of them views?

Comment: And why do you need 4 identical joins to `deployments`? This probably creates a huge cross join. I'm curious, what does the `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deployments WHERE asset_configuration_id = 169;` return?

Comment: @ypercube views have the prefix "vw_"... we're talking about a regular table. The count shows 55. The goal of this statement is to become a view... all this because 5.1 doesn't support sub selects in views. The views fetch the latest dates for PKs so that I can join on them with the deployments table.

Comment: Then the 4 joins to `deployments` will create 55^4 rows which is about 7M rows. Try removing the `d2,d3,d4` and joining all the tables to `d1`.

Comment: @ypercube based on the comments in the query, don't I need to join to those individual instances of deployments in order to obtain the different values that the inner join will create (Due to the potential difference in dates)?

Comment: Hm, yes, you might need the joins. The problem is then the views. Every view probably results in a temporary table during the execution of the query. And then indexes cannot be used on these temporary tables. Not in version 5.1. It's not going to be easy but I'd try rewriting without views or derived tables, as a huge query. The difficulty of such a rewritting depends on the complexity of the views.

Comment: @ypercube I added an example of the view to guage the impact...

Comment: @ypercube added the full statement with views extracted... again, it clogs up with the last two inner join added. If I comment them out, it works under a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making a temp table with just the data you need and doing a join to that. For each self join do another temp table. I would start with one at a time and check the performance.

Comment: I've identified that it's the fourth inner join to deployments that makes the query very slow. If I get that out, the three previous joins work fine providing a result under one second.

Answer (score 0):

Test the inner query to see how well it performs.  If you are missing an index on the foreign key, performance may be very slow.

The size of your result set can cause performance issues with inner joins. The inner join may need to be run once for each row in your result set.

Not having enough memory can cause an issue as data may need to be re-read from disk.  Try using `sar` to monitor disk activity while the query is running.  If it increases significantly then this may be an issue.  Monitor when running the query two times in a row to see if the data is being buffered.